# Can we evaluate this limit? $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+}a \int_{b}^{-\log a}\frac{e^y}y \, dy$

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Does the following limit exist?

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+}a \int_{b}^{-\log a}\frac{e^y}y \, dy$$

I suspect it might be $0$, but am unable to get anything concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$ \lim_{a \rightarrow 0+} a \displaystyle \int_{b}^{-log \ a}\frac{e^y}{y}dy =\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{  \int_{b}^{-log \ a}\frac{e^y}{y}dy }{\frac{1}{a}}=\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{  \int_{b}^{\log z}\frac{e^y}{y}dy }{z}$$

Show that this is of $\infty/\infty$ type and apply L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

Sooner or later, you will learn that
$$\int \frac {e^y} y \,dy=\text{Ei}(y)$$ which the definition of the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

So
$$I=\int_b^{-\log(a)} \frac {e^y} y \,dy=\text{Ei}(-\log (a))-\text{Ei}(b)$$

On the other hand (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12)), for large values of $x$
$$\text{Ei}(x)\sim \frac {e^x} x \left(1+\frac{1!}x+\frac{2!}{x^2}+\frac{3!}{x^3}+\cdots\right)$$
So, limited to the first term
$$\text{Ei}(-\log (a))\sim -\frac{1}{a \log (a)}$$ and
$$a I\sim -\frac{1}{ \log (a)}- a\, \text{Ei}(b)$$